# c# dynamic object - where is get

Tags: c#

I have question about c# properly like ViewBag in ASP.NET MVC
We have this code :

```
public dynamic ViewBag { get; }
```

and we can do this:

```
ViewBag.foo="foo";
```

and question is : why we can set object, if we don't have set?

Thank for help : ).

Comment: Not having `set` on the `ViewBag` object means we can't assign to *it*, not to its members.

Comment: So we get object, and set property in this object ? Thank You for help : )

Comment: @Sangun Yes - you get the value of the `ViewBag` property as an object and set properties on that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set the object, only its property (foo).

Comment: So we get object, and set property in this object ? Thank You for help : )

Comment: OK, if this is a good answer, please accept the answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers